# Read data in form '1.4523e-9'

Tags: r, csv, type-conversion

I'm trying to read data from a `*.txt` or `*.csv` file into R with `read.table` or `read.csv`. However, my data is written as *e.g.* `1.4523e-9` in the file denoting `1.4523*10^{-9}` though ggplot recognizes this as a string instead of a real. Is there some sort of `eval( )`-function to convert this to its correct value ?

Comment: Have you tried as.numeric?

Comment: I guess you need to inspect your data set with `str()`

Comment: @CactusWoman as.numeric stops at the `.`, _i.e._ `1.4523e-9` is read as `1`.

Comment: @CactusWoman @MaratTalipov  a solution seems `as.numeric(as.character(...))` but this looks very cumbersome.

Comment: What format is your data in exactly? Because as.numeric("1.4523e-9") returns the number 1.4523e-09. If your data are in factor form, you could try instead to read them in as strings using stringsAsFactors argument of read.csv/read.table

Comment: Those are not 'character' mode after being read by any of the read.* functions. They were factors. They could have been coerced to numeric at input with `colClasses=c( ...,"numeric",...)` where the numeric entry was properly placed. Read `?read.table` regarding how to use `colClasses`..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the exact format of the `csv` file you import,`read.csv` and `read.table` often simply convert all columns to factors. Since a straightforward conversion to numeric as failed, I assume this is your problem. You can change this using the `colClasses` argument as such:

```
# if every column should be numeric:
df <- read.csv("foobar.csv", colClasses = "numeric")

#if only some columns should be numeric, use a vector.
#to read the first as factor and the second as numeric:
read.csv("foobar.csv", colClasses = c("factor", "numeric")
```

Of course, both of the above are barebones examples; you probably want to supply other arguments as well, eg `header = T`.

If you don't want to supply the classes of each column when you read the table (maybe you don't know them yet!), you can convert after the fact using either of the following:

```
df$a <- as.numeric(as.character(a)) #as you already discovered
df$a <- as.numeric(levels(df$a)[df$a])
```

Yes, these are both clunky, but they are standard and frequently [recommended.](http://www.r-bloggers.com/convert-factors-to-numbers/)